# Provide local fallback for CSS from CDN

Tags: javascript, css, cdn

I'm loading the Bootstrap CSS on my page from the CDN [bootstrapcdn.com](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com)

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

How can I test if the stylesheet was loaded, and if not provide a local fallback?

I **do not** want to wait for jQuery or other libraries to load before doing the test; I want all CSS to be loaded on the page first.

Comment: That could be challenging, because I *think* CSS loads asynchronously.

Comment: You do not want JQuery or other resources to be loaded, but the code I shared below is a pure javascript code and there is no dependency on jQuery (I think). Without using javascript, I do not know of any other way of achieving what you are looking for. Unless of course, some sort of revision to the w3 spec where you can specify fallback library - which I think would be a very good update to spec in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I have created for our needs. If this meets your needs, simply call the function ensureCssFileInclusion(file to check, boolean value). You will have to adjust it for your needs to make sure that you provide the cssFileToCheck, fallbackCssFile in this function.

```
/**
 * Checks the page for given CSS file name to see if it was already included within page stylesheets.
 * If it was, then this function does nothing else. If CSS file was not found among page stylesheets,
 * then this function will attempt to load the stylesheet by adding an HTML link tag to the document
 * HEAD section. You must also specify whether given cssFileToInclude is a relative path or an absolute path.
 */
ensureCssFileInclusion = function(cssFileToInclude, isRelativePath) {
   if (isRelativePath) {
     if (!window.location.origin) {
        cssFileToInclude = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.host + cssFileToInclude;
     }
   }
   var styleSheets = document.styleSheets;
   for (var i = 0, max = styleSheets.length; i < max; i++) {
     if (styleSheets[i].href == cssFileToInclude) {
        return;
     }
   }
   // because no matching stylesheets were found, we will add a new HTML link element to the HEAD section of the page.
   var link = document.createElement("link");
   link.rel = "stylesheet";
   link.href = cssFileToInclude;
   document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
};
```

Comment: Does this work cross-browser without problems? Any issues with page load time?

Comment: We are in pre-prod right now, but this function has been in place for about a year and we haven't seen anything that would concern us. One thing I always remind to those who are concerned about (or try to optimize) 30ms processes like this is.... we paddle way too much junk (javascripts/css/images) etc. to the client machine anyways, that this 20/30 ms won't change a thing. Second, if this was 20/30ms on the server that is catering to millions of clients, I might be think'bout it, but modern day clients with multi-core processors and 4+GB RAM are capable of handling this.

Comment: On your question of "Does this work cross-browser without problems?"... its pure javascript, so as long as you are catering to a javascript-enabled browser, i can't see why it wouldn't work!

Comment: Out of curiosity, in what way is this code better than, say, `<link rel="stylesheet" href="cdn.css" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.href='local.css';" />`? (which perhaps didn't exist back then, just asking for current use)